# Modifying a cooldown decorator to work for methods instead of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a decorator which would work for methods to apply a "cooldown" on them, meaning they can't be called multiple times within a certain duration. I already created one for functions:

```
>>> @cooldown(5)
... def f():
...     print('f() was called')
...
>>> f()
f() was called
>>> f()  # Nothing happens when called immediately
>>> f()  # This is 5 seconds after first call
f() was called
```

but I need this to support methods of classes instead of normal functions:

```
>>> class Test:
...    @cooldown(6)
...    def f(self, arg):
...        print(self, arg)
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.f(1)
<Test object at ...> 1
>>> t.f(2)
>>> t.f(5)  # Later
<Test object at ...> 5
```

Here's what I created to make it work for normal functions:

```
import time

class _CooldownFunc:
    def __init__(self, func, duration):
        self._func = func
        self.duration = duration
        self._start_time = 0

    @property
    def remaining(self):
        return self.duration - (time.time() - self._start_time)

    @remaining.setter
    def remaining(self, value):
        self._start_time = time.time() - (self.duration - value)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.remaining = self.duration
            return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self._func.__getattribute__(attr)


def cooldown(duration):
    def decorator(func):
        return _CooldownFunc(func, duration)
    return decorator
```

But this doesn't work with methods, since it passes the `_CooldownFunction` object as `self` and ignores the original `self` completely.
How would I get it to work with methods, properly passing the original `self` instead of the `_CooldownFunction` object?

Also, it is required for users to be able to change the remaining time on the fly, which makes this even harder (can't just use `__get__` to return `functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)` or something):

```
>>> class Test:
...     @cooldown(10)
...     def f(self, arg): 
...         print(self, arg)
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.f(5)
<Test object at ...> 5
>>> t.f.remaining = 0
>>> t.f(3)  # Almost immediately after previous call
<Test object at ...> 3
```

**Edit:** It only needs to work for methods, not for both methods and functions.

**Edit 2:** There's a huge flaw in this design to begin with. While it works just fine for normal functions, I want it to decorate each instance separately. Currently if I were to have two instances `t1` and `t2` and were to call `t1.f()`, I could not longer call `t2.f()` because the cooldown is teid to the `f()` method instead of the instances. I probably could use some kind of dictionary for this, but after this realization I'm even more lost...

Comment: Note that the decorator's `__call__` only gets called once, returning the function that is getting called afterwards. Have you tried enclosing your test in a closure and returning that?

Comment: @Felk The `cooldown` function is the decorator, not the `_CooldownFunc` class. The `cooldown` decorator replaces the original function with a `_CooldownFunc` object. So when you're trying to call the original function, you're actually invoking the `_CooldownFunc` object's `__call__`, which checks the cooldown and internally cals the original function stored into the `_func` attribute. So yeah, the `__call__` gets called everytime you call the decorated function. It's working perfectly for normal functions, but the methods' `self` parameter is bringing in trouble.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry. But then again the `cooldown` decorator shouldn't create a new instance of `_CooldownFunc` for each invocation of `func` like it does now, right?

Comment: @Felk Sure it should, the `_CooldownFunc` is what contains the durations and start times for individual functions. If I want to have multiple functions decorated with a cooldown, I need them all to have separate start times and durations, thus I need a new `_CooldownFunc` object for every function.

Comment: @Felk Ups I think I misread your question. It doesn't create a new instance of `_CooldownFunc` for every invokation of a certain function, it creates a new instance of `_CooldownFunc` for every function. It basically takes a function as an input and replaces the function with a `_CooldownFunc` object, which can then be called as if it were the original input function.

Comment: Yeah, I got you. The code makes sense to me now, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Markus do you only need `remaining` to be able to reset the timeout?

Comment: @user2683246 No, that was just one example. I need it to be able to change and adjust the remaining time as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your class's `__get__` method to make it a descriptor. The `__get__` method will be called when someone gets the decorated method from within its containing object, and is passed the containing object, which you will then be able to pass to the original method. It returns an object which implements the functionality you need.

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    return Wrapper(self, obj)
```

The `Wrapper` object implements `__call__`, and any properties you want, so move those implementations into that object. It would look like:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, cdfunc, obj):
        self.cdfunc = cdfunc
        self.obj = obj
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #do stuff...
        self.cdfunc._func(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
    @property
    def remaining(self):
        #...get needed things from self.cdfunc
```

Comment: This is a really nice approach which I hadn't thought of. However, it doesn't allow me to access the `remaining` attribute as shown in the end of my question. This is a vital part of my program.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Ah, I didn't notice that part of the question. If using getter/setter functions rather than a property is good enough, you can easily add them (e.g. `inner.get_remaining = lambda: cf.remaining`). Otherwise I'm not sure how it could be implemented.

Comment: That's better than nothing, but still not perfect. I'll wait and think if me or someone else could come up with a solution that would allow the property to be used.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I just did come up with one.

Comment: I was just after something similar with `__get__`, but you were faster, looks nice and seems to work! But would this approach be safe if the method would be accessed from two objects at as-close-as-possible-of-the-same time? Like, first one accesses the method and the `obj` gets set to the first instance, then midway of execution the `obj` would change to the second instance and the first instance's execution would finish incorrectly using the second obj's data?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen You're right, I didn't think this through. I have another solution but it gets a bit complicated, will edit in a minute.

Comment: I just realized a huge flaw in my design. The decorator is supposed to give each instance their own remaining cooldown, instead of the currect way where if one instance call the method, it goes on cooldown and the other one can't call it either. Will update the original question...

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Oh, I thought that was intentional. I have a new solution now that solves your original issue. For this new issue, you can store the cooldown times in a member of the `obj` passed to `__get__` instead of in `_CooldownFunc`. You just need to make sure to check if they have been set yet with `hasattr`.

Comment: Okay this is starting to look really nice! What do you think of [this](https://gist.github.com/Mahi/c0b8bcb0231d91db626b) implementation I came up with (thanks to you that is), any flaws or downsides compared to storing the cooldown times into the `obj` itself? This even allows each bound method to change its own cooldownusing `self.<function>.cooldown` without changing every functions cooldown!

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen That requires the object to be hashable, and it will share the same cooldown between objects that compare as equal. It also leaks memory (the hash entry is kept when an object is deleted), but that can be fixed with a `WeakKeyDictionary`. You can hash by `id(obj)` instead, but that also won't work 100% either because a new object can have the same id as a previously deleted object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will still look more into the `WeakKeyDictionary`, but for now I just added `__del__` to the `obj` which removes the `obj` from the dictionary. And I think `id(obj)` is good enough for my purpose, I ended up using that one for now, thanks for all the help and effort you put into this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the issue interjay addressed, I did a quick re-write of your cooldown decorator, which now works for all kinds of functions/methods:

```
class cooldown(object):
    def __init__(self, duration):
        self._duration = duration
        self._storage = self
        self._start_time = 0

    def __getRemaining(self):
        if not hasattr(self._storage, "_start_time"):
            self._storage._start_time = 0
        return self._duration - (time.time() -
                                 self._storage._start_time)

    def __setRemaining(self, value):
        self._storage._start_time = time.time() - (self._duration -
                                                   value)

    remaining = property(__getRemaining, __setRemaining)

    def __call__(self, func):
        is_method = inspect.getargspec(func).args[0] == 'self'
        def call_if(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_method :
                self._storage = args[0]
            else:
                self._storage = self
            if self.remaining <= 0:
                self.remaining = self._duration
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

        call_if.setRemaining = self.__setRemaining
        call_if.getRemaining = self.__getRemaining
        return call_if
```

Tests:

```
@cooldown(2)
def foo(stuff):
    print("foo: %s" % stuff)

foo(1)
foo(2)
time.sleep(3)
foo(3)
foo.setRemaining(0)
foo(4)

class Bla(object):
    @cooldown(2)
    def bar(self, stuff):
        print("bar: %s" % stuff)

bla = Bla()
bla.bar(1)
bla.bar.setRemaining(0)
bla.bar(2)
time.sleep(3)
bla.bar(3)
bla.bar(4)
```

outputs:

```
foo: 1
foo: 3
foo: 4
bar: 1
bar: 2
bar: 3
```

EDIT: I altered the code so it works independently for multiple instances by putting it's storage into the invoked function's `self` argument. Please note that this purely relies on the first argument being named "self", but you can search for a more robust way of detecting if a decorated callable is a method or a function if you need more security here.

EDIT2: This might has a bug if you do `instance1.foo()` and then try to do `instance2.foo.setRemaining(0)`. Since the context didn't get switched, this would set the remaining value for instance1. Could be fixed by making the setters and getters bound methods to the context, but this is getting messy. I will stop here for now

Comment: I don't think this approach supports the `remaining`  attribute either, unfortunately.

Comment: It does now. I simply added getters and setters to the decorated function. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how (or even if) it would be possible to append getters and setters as a property

Comment: See my edit to the original question, I was being careless and didn't think this through, my original code didn't work as I intended it to. It needs to have a separate cooldown for each instance. Is this even possible anymore? :D

Comment: Yeah, got that, removed my comment

Comment: This is really nice, but I think I'll go with @interjay's approach since that allows me to keep the `remaining` as a property. Thank you very much for the effor though, I actually learned some new things thanks to you! :) I already gave you an upvote, but I would give a second one if I could.

Answer (score 0):

This decorator works both with functions and methods, supports `remaining` property and is implemented as a single class.

```py
import time

class cooldown:
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.calltime = time.time() - timeout
        self.func = None
        self.obj = None
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.func is None:
            self.func = args[0]
            return self
        now = time.time()
        if now - self.calltime >= self.timeout:
            self.calltime = now
            if self.obj is None:
                return self.func.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return self.func.__get__(self.obj, self.objtype)(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        self.obj = obj
        self.objtype = objtype
        return self
    @property
    def remaining(self):
        now = time.time()
        delta = now - self.calltime
        if delta >= self.timeout:
            return 0
        return self.timeout - delta
    @remaining.setter
    def remaining(self, value):
        self.calltime = time.time() - self.timeout + value
```

```py
# test with functions
@cooldown(8)
def test(*args):
    print('Function', *args)

>>> test()
Function
>>> test()
>>> test.remaining
4.718205213546753
>>> test.remaining = 0
>>> test()
Function
```

```py
# test with methods
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    @cooldown(5)
    def a(self, *args):
        print('Method', self.value, *args)

>>> a = A(7)
>>> a.a()
Method 7
>>> a.a()
>>> a.a.remaining
3.589237892348223
>>> a.a.remaining = 10
>>> a.a(32)
>>> a.a.remaining
8.423482288923785
>>> a.a.remaining = 0
>>> a.a(32)
Method 7 32
```